# Understanding crossdomain.xml and malicious scripting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get my head around why only javascript code can only call back to the same domain the page is hosted from and I understand that you do not want the code sending personal details etc to another domain (could be a malicious site).

However, if the other domain puts a crossDomain.xml file on their server, does that mean now a malicious site could accept calls?

As you can guess I have a rudimentary understanding of how this works, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: yes, if you allow all domains, but as @Quentin said, also you can allow only domains that you trust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Site A publishes a suitable crossDomain.xml file then Site B can use Adobe Flash to read data from Site A. This has nothing to do with JavaScript.

The JavaScript equivalent is [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

In either case, the permission given should be either:

- For data that is not confidential
- To sites that are trusted

In the first case, if Site B is malicious then it can't do anything bad with the data. In the second, the developer of Site A has made a serious mistake in trusting Site B.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I came across CORS earlier today and wanted to know if it was the same as crossDomain.xml, so thanks for the reply. Having not worked with Flash, from Javascript, if I use a third-party plugin and that plugin was making cross domain calls, my question was how can this be prevented? In other words, what if CORS was setup on the third party server, wouldn't this mean that cross site calls could be accepted on the malicious server?

Comment: @JD. I can't tell which server is which and how the third party plugin is involved in  your comment. CORS allows Site A to grant permission to Site B to read data from Site A. If Site B uses third party JS, then that third party JS can read data from Site A because it is running on Site B. There is no way for Site A to tell what JavaScript running on Site B was written by Developer X and which was written by Developer Y.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help out.